# Comparing Multiple Lists of Data in Excel to find gaps

Tags: excel, comparison, product, correlation

I am conducting a product analysis and have data on all the products my company has and need to compare that against all the products that our competitors have.  I need to find out where the gaps are, in particular what products do they have that we don't? from the multiple lists of data I have on each competitors products lists against our product data list.
What is the best formula to use or way to find and interpret this data in Excel?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables using Power query.

- Table 1 = your company
- key = Product
- Table2 through TableN= competitors
- key = Product
- Combine the competitors tables into a single table.
- Do a `nestedjoin` with `JoinKind.RightAnti` which will return all the products in Table 2 that do not exist in Table 1
- We use a Nested join since the `keys` have the same Column Header

[image]

**M Code**
*You can paste this code into the Power Query Advanced Editor, and change the `Name=` argument in lines 2 through `N` to reflect your actual table names*

*If you have many competitors, it is possible to create a function to gather all the table names, but overkill for just a few*

Step through `Applied Steps` in the Power Query UI to see what each line does.

```
let
    myCompany = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="myCompany"]}[Content],
    otherCompany = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="otherCompany"]}[Content],
    company3 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="company3"]}[Content],

//Join the competitor tables
    competitors = Table.Combine({otherCompany,company3}),

//finde the missing
    missing = Table.NestedJoin(myCompany,"Product",competitors,"Product", "Missing", JoinKind.RightAnti),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(missing,{"Product", "Description"}),
    #"Expanded Missing" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Missing", {"Product", "Description"}, {"Missing.Product", "Missing.Description"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Missing",{{"Missing.Product", Order.Ascending}})
    
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely do this type of comparison in a different system than Excel.
However, if you definitely want to do it in Excel and only want to compare the products, you can do it like this:

1 Sheet contains a table with all the competitors products.
If the competitor is also important to know, then add that too...

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product a | competitor a |
| 2 | product b | competitor b |
| 3 | product c | competitor a |

Then use 1 Sheet with a list of your product and a vlookup to check if the competitor has it. You also add vlookup to the competitor list to see if you have what they got.

Your products list:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product a | `=vlookup(A1;$Sheet1.A:B;2;FALSE)` |
| 2 | product b | `=vlookup(B1;$Sheet1.A:B;2;FALSE)` |
| 3 | product c | `=vlookup(AC;$Sheet1.A:B;2;FALSE)` |

Column B will show which competitor has this.

Add the same kind of vlookup to the competitor too.

Depending on your Excel version, it could be that you should use , instead of ; and the vlookup could be called something in a different language.

Comment: That's great, much appreciated, thanks.  What other systems other than Excel would you recommend using to do this sort of comparison?  Have never done this kind of analysis before.

Comment: I think relational databases are a good tool for this type of comparison. The answer about using power query is doing just that.